# Find $\frac{BC}{CD}$ in $\triangle ABC$ in which AB=AC and BD bisects $\angle B$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In triangle $ABC$, $\angle A = 36^\circ$ and $\angle B = \angle C = 72^\circ$. Let $\overline{BD}$ be the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$.

(a) Prove that $BC = BD = AD$.

(b) Let $x = BC$ and let $y = CD$. Using similar triangles $ABC$ and $BCD$, write an equation relating $x$ and $y$.

(c) Write the equation from Part b in terms of $r=\frac yx$ and find $r.$

(d) Compute $\cos 36^\circ$ and $\cos 72^\circ$ using Parts a-c.

I could solve (a) and (b) but I am stuck at (c). In fact I even know how to solve (d) once (c) is solved. My answer to (b) was $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{x+y}{x}$. I tried manipulating this equation in various ways but could not succeed in finding the value of $\frac{y}{x}$

Comment: See [angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem).

Comment: This problem becomes a whole lot easier when you just draw a regular pentagon.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$\frac xy=\frac{x+y}{x}\iff \frac{1}{\frac yx}=1+\frac yx\iff \frac 1r=1+r\iff 1=r+r^2$$

Comment: I have come up till here. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier. But I am stuck at this point.

Comment: @Gayatri: I added a bit. Does that help?

Comment: I get $y=\frac{1+sqrt(5)}{2}$ , $\frac{1-sqrt(5)}{2}$. Is it correct?

Comment: @Gayatri: Yes, but the latter is negative. So, $\color{red}{r}=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$sin(18)$

I will suppose you work in degrees here.

It is easier to compute $cos(72) = sin(18)$, because

Now we know that $cos(2x) = 2(cos(x))^2-1$ and we can derive that: know that $cos(2x)=cos(3x)$

$ cos(3x)=4cos^3x-3cosx$

So when you take $t = cosx$, we can make an equation in $t$ having 
$t = cos(72)$ as root. Then $cos(2x) = cos(3x)$ becomes so $2t^2-1=4t^3-3t$
solving this cubic we get and resubstituting $t=cos(72)$ $sin(18) = cos(72) = \frac{-1}{4} +\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{5}$. this is another way hope it helps you to solve part c and also $cos36$.